# Return a boolean from an applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet, boolean, joptionpane

I want to create the following code into an applet (cause now when I copied to the server doesn't work and after my search JOptionpane is only for local) and I want this applet to return the boolean "addLineItem" back to my jsp site who also will be call it from there.

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
        String sqlprod = " SELECT LORD, LPROD, LLINE"
                   + " FROM ECL "
                   + " WHERE LORD = " + myOrd 
                   + " AND LPROD = '"  + jspSp.with("LTXT").getValue() + "'";

        Statement stmtDupli = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsDupli = stmtDupli.executeQuery(sqlprod);

        if(rsDupli.next()){
                dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The product is in the position " + rsDupli.getInt("LLINE") + " already!", "WARNING", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
                if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                    addLineItem = false;
                }
        }
```

and can also please write me the way that I write the call into the JSP for this applet.

---

Here I have create this simply applet

```
public class g7appletDialog extends Applet {

public boolean action(boolean addnewLine){

    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;

    dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The product bla bla ", "WARNING", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    }else {
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }
}//close boolean method
```

}
and have problem how I can call it into the JSP site 
here is the thing I have write in the JSP site

```
%><%@ page language="java" %>
        <jsp:plugin type="applet" code="g7appletDialog.class" codebase="D:\GET2\workspace\AppletDialog\appletDialog" width="250" height="50">
        <jsp:fallback><B>Unable to start plugin!</B></jsp:fallback>
        </jsp:plugin> %><%
```

when I do the debbuging dont get anything either error neither results..the pop - up window for example

Comment: Confusion here: JSP is server side, an applet runs in the clients browser. An applet may call JSP by means of some AJAX call.

Comment: *aah!* Use prepared statements. You're leaving yourself wide open to `SQL` injection. Especially on a web based `applet`.

Comment: The problem for the Applet Solution is because the  dialogbox doesnt appeared at ALL ...when I copied at the server

Comment: Or at least I can make an applet just the dialogButton?

Comment: I don't think many users leave Java turned on in the browser these days. I don't. If I go to a site and it requires an Applet, I leave. You'd be better off just using HTML for the interface and making your dialogue box with jQuery.

Comment: it going to be for specific users only, and I have found the solution of making an applet cause want to use this same applet like a method to call it also from others JSP Site. My focus is the JOptionPane to working good!

Comment: Your backend logic (the method) should be in servlets. That will make it easier to call from other JSPs or even other sites (not clear on which you mean). But don't put the actual logic in the Applet. And using an Applet for the frontend rather than just HTML means that you are using Java on the user's machine, and so if your users are ever hit by a Java update your site might cease working for them. You generally get stuck with one version of Java you need on the user's machine with this approach.